# insert trigger: issue with constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I'm trying to create trigger on **customer-order** database where each customer has *several orders* and each order has *several items*.

I'm planning to create a trigger to ensure that

> the total  number of all orders place by the same customer cannot
>   exceed 10000

How can create the insert trigger for above constraint.

Here is my SQL file with sample data provided.

```
 CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
 USE `mydb` ;


CREATE TABLE customers
(`id` int not null auto_increment primary key, `first_name` varchar(64), `last_name`varchar(64) );

INSERT INTO customers(`first_name`, `last_name`)VALUES('Jhon', 'Doe');

CREATE TABLE items
(`id` int not null auto_increment primary key,`item` varchar(64),`price` decimal(19,2));

INSERT INTO items(`item`, `price`)VALUES('Item1', 10.5),('Item2', 25);

CREATE TABLE orders
(`id` int not null auto_increment primary key, `date` date, `customer_id` int,`status` int not null default 1, -- 1 new constraint fk_customer_id foreign key (customer_id) references customers (id));

INSERT INTO orders(`date`, `customer_id`, `status`)VALUES(CURDATE(), 1, 1);

CREATE TABLE order_items(`id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
 `order_id` int not null, `item_id` int not null, `quantity` decimal(19,3) not null,  `price` decimal(19,3) not null,
constraint fk_order_id foreign key (order_id) references orders (id),
constraint fk_item_id  foreign key (item_id) references items (id));

INSERT INTO order_items(`order_id`, `item_id`, `quantity`, `price`)VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 10.5),(1, 2, 4, 25);
```

;

Comment: I'm using MySQL database

Comment: You can use check constraints instead of trigger

Comment: why do it in a trigger. consider disallowing in the insert call. Better yet, when they click on Place an Order, issue the notification "You cannot place an order. You have bought too much from us"

Comment: I have tried with Check constraint ,It worked.But I want to learn how this can be achieved with TRIGGERS.Please Help me as I'm new to triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Jahul's answer would technically work, here is alternative logic:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `customer_orders_check`
BEFORE INSERT ON `orders` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((select count(*) 
         from `orders` 
         where a.customer_id = NEW.customer_id
        ) >= 10000 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Too many orders already';
    END IF;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

That said, I would suggest an alternative approach.  Counting up to 10,000 rows for each insert seems like a lot of work.  Instead, keep the counter in the `customers` table, using an after insert trigger (and perhaps after update/delete as well).  Then when inserting a new row, you can just check the count in customers.

Answer (score 0):

This trigger will stop insert --

```
CREATE TRIGGER `customer_orders_check`
BEFORE INSERT ON `orders` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF exists(select count(*) 
    from `orders` a 
    where a.customer_id= NEW.customer_id
    having count(*)>=10000 ) THEN
SET NEW.id = 1 ;
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Would it be more useful to return using a [SIGNAL: as the way to “return” an error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) that indicates the exact error?